# autowiring beans doesn't work

Tags: spring, autowired, jdbctemplate

I have one class:

```
@Configuration
public abstract class JDBCConnFactory  {        
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    @Bean
    public SimpleJdbcOperations jdbcConnection(DataSource dataSource){
        return new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

And I try to use bean jdbcConnection in another class:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("jdbcConnection")
private SimpleJdbcOperations dbConn;
```

And I get the error:

```
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcOperations] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=jdbcConnection)}
```

or another exception:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jdbcConnection' is defined
```

where is my bug? Why it couldn't find jdbcConnection bean?

Comment: Probably look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370961/nosuchbeandefinitionexception-at-least-1-bean-which-qualifies-as-autowire-candid).

Comment: No my problem is exactly in:  org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jdbcConnection' is defined

Comment: Your Qualifier values need to match or you can just remove both Qualifier annotations entirely if there is only one bean defined within Spring of type SimpleJdbcOperations as Spring will be able to autowire successfully just by looking at object types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move `@Qualifier("dataSource")` to properly autowire datasource

```
public SimpleJdbcOperations jdbcConnection(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) { ... }
```

Then either remove `@Qualifier("jdbcConnection")` and simply use

```
@Autowired
private SimpleJdbcOperations dbConn;
```

or set bean name in the `JDBCConnFactory` class and keep `@Qualifier("jdbcConnection")` as you have now, like so:

```
@Configuration
public abstract class JDBCConnFactory  {        
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "jdbcConnection")
    public SimpleJdbcOperations jdbcConnection(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource){
        return new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

If you have several different datasources and `SimpleJdbcOperations`, then second option is preferable. Otherwise, I think the first one is simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at section 5.9.3 of the spring framework reference.  It covers qualifiers.

You're qualifiers do not match, thus spring can not resolve your autowiring.  Try this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("dataSource")
private SimpleJdbcOperations dbConn;
```