# Why does my Bean not qualify as Autowire Candidate on Junit test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, junit

I have the following test class, which aims to run junit tests for my `Service` class in my `MVC` model. This is my class `ExpertsServiceTest.java`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class ExpertsServiceTest {


    @Autowired
    private  ExpertRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private ExpertsServiceImpl service;


    Experts demoExpert = new Experts(ObjectId.get(),"Steve Jobs", "Enterpreneur",
            Availability.BUSY, Language.CHINESE);



    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        service.deleteAll();
        service.createExpert(demoExpert);

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception{
        service.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindAll(){
        List<Experts> expertEntries = service.findAll();
        assertEquals(2, expertEntries.size());
    }
}
```

However when I run the test, I bump into the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demo.ExpertsServiceTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'demo.ExpertRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:393)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'demo.ExpertRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    ... 27 more
```

Does anyone understand why this happens and how I could go about resolving it? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [No found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095881/no-found-for-dependency-expected-at-least-1-bean-which-qualifies-as-autowire-ca)

Comment: you need `@SpringBootTest` annotation for integration test cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not providing the application context information

Please annotate the test class with @ContextConfiguration and provide a configuration class. Something as follows

```
package com.example;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
// ApplicationContext will be loaded from the OrderServiceConfig class
@ContextConfiguration(classes=OrderServiceConfig.class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class OrderServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    @Test
    public void testOrderService() {
        // test the orderService
    }
}
```

[Source](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the spring context, you should use: '@SpringBootTest' annotation.
You can read more here: [SpringRunner vs SpringBootTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58901288/springrunner-vs-springboottest)